# ScrollMagic and TweenMax Automatically executes

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

Hey all Im trying to wrap my head around all this, been playing with it all day.  What I'm trying to accomplish is have a background image zoom in (and eventually become transparent through opacity) when the user scrolls down.  I've got one half of the desired effect working but It doesn't seem to want to work on user scroll, it just automatically executes.

It must be something simple but Im pretty new to this.

here is the code I've written

```
    var tween = TweenMax.to('#regular', 0.5, {
    scale: 2
    });

    // Init Controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();


    // Create the Scene and trigger when visible with ScrollMagic
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#featured-image',
    reverse: true,
    offset: 700
    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(controller)
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjWLyO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that the `setTween` method of your scene is not available & this is because you are missing an include of `animation.gsap.min.js` important plugin in your codepen when it comes to using **TweenMax** alongside **ScrollMagic**.

So add [this external javascript](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js) after your `ScrollMagic` include in your pen and you are gold.

Comment: Hi Tahir, 
I see myself in the same issue and i have the animation included. Still the tweens are executed at page load. The if i scroll down, nothing is executed (just like I would be already at the bottom of the page). 

When I scroll back up and down again, everything executes properly.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: hello @mkbrv! it has been a while I have used either ScrollMagic or TweenMax so my knowledge may be a little dated plus I am sure things may have changed quite a bit since then. however, there is [GreenSock Forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) as well as [Github Issues for ScrollMagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues) where you can try asking your question or simply try asking a new question of your own here at SO with relevant tags, reproducible problem and details and I am sure someone will be able to help you out. I apologise I couldn't help you. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, although I am using the above-described javascript solution. 
For my specific case I found a solution described here:

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16014-staggerfrom-always-runs-on-page-load-not-on-scroll-magic-event/

Set in each tween the parameter: immediateRender : false

I am also running a TweenMax call to set the initial parameters after all scene init.